# Traders view Pine script - Green& red candle count for the session/day

Tags: pine-script

Hello Pine code Experts,

The code below is giving the candle count increment for the session. I want to calculate green and red candles from the session start. Also, I want to count at any point of time how many green and red candles are formed till time.

Please help me to modify the below code.

```
/////////////////
//@version=4
study("SinceyNew")
res = "D"
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
plot(barssince(is_newbar(res)))
```

Thank you
Raj

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example

```
t = change(time("D"))
up = close > open ? 1 : 0
dn = close < open ? 1 : 0
a=0.,a := t ? up : a[1] + up
b=0.,b := t ? dn : b[1] + dn
```

The counter reinitialize when a new session start.